# htaccess - Point domain and a sub domain to a folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have two folders on FTP root. `site_v1` and `site_v2`. site_v2 has new version of website and site_v1 has older version. I wanted to point my domain to `site_v2`, the latest version. So I made an .htaccess on root as under.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !site_v2/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site_v2/$1 [L]
```

This works well. When I open http://example.com; site_v2 loads seamlessly.

Then, for site_v1, I created a sub domain http://old.example.com and pointed it to site_v1 folder; I get this error when I run http://old.example.com.

```
The requested URL /site_v1/site_v2/site_v1/index.html 
was not found on this server.
```

I am clueless. It seems that http://old.example.com is still pointing to site_v2 because of .htaccess on root. What could be the solution so I can force old.example.com to load in `site_v1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site_v[0-9]/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_v2/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site_v[0-9]/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_v1/$1 [L]
```

This way, the host matching against the `%{HTTP_HOST} var won't overlap.